# How many have {a number} At least one time

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i have seen a lot of this question and i have use a type but not sure about it.

> Positives numbers that are even, smaller than 100000, and which have at least one instance of the digit 5 or 7

What about it this guys,if you could solve it simple and clear it.Cause what i have done alone it doesn't lead to nowhere.Thanks in advance.If you could tell me how to think in this case i will be greatful.

Comment: Do you mean "numbers that are even, smaller than 100000, and which have at least one instance of the digit $5$ or $7$" or do you mean "numbers that are smaller than 100000 and have at least one instance of the digit $5$ or $7$"?  There are about half as many of the former.

Comment: the first one, i didn't wrote it well ,i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about 5 digit numbers.  The last digit is even and one or more of the first 4 digits is 5 or 7.  To solve this, first get the number of 4 digit numbers where none of the digits is 5 or 7.  This is simply $8^4=4096$.  Therefore there are 5904 4 digit numbers containing 5 or 7.  Since the last digit must be even, the total you want is 29520.

Comment: I suspect that by 'numbers', OP is referring to positive integers, in which case the answer is in fact 29519 as your method is entirely sound but for it counting 0.

Comment: yes it is positives numbers only

Comment: You think all this alone?

Comment: 00000 is not on the list in any case, either by omitting it at the start or by being omitted at the end, so 29520 is correct for the count of numbers containing a 5 or a 7.